# MySQL order by count for last hour recursive

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-order-by

I have a SQL question. First of all I'd like to know is it even possible with just SQL, and if not does anyone know a good workaround.

We are building a site, where users can vote for videos.
The users can vote by SMS or directly on site after Facebook authentication.
We have to make a top list of all videos, and calculate the "position" on the list for each video.

So far, we have done that with a simple subquery, something like this:

```
SELECT v.video_id AS id, 
    (SELECT (COUNT(*)+1) FROM videos AS v2 
        WHERE (v2.SMS_votes + v2.facebook_votes) > (v.SMS_votes + v.facebook_votes)) AS total_position 
FROM videos AS v
```

`SMS_votes` and `facebook_votes` are aggregated fields. There are separate tables for each kind of votes, with records for each vote, including the time the vote has been set.

This works fine, the positions are calculated... if 2 or more videos have the same number of votes, they "share" the position.

Unfortunately there can be no position sharing, and we have to resolve it by the following rules:

- if 2 videos have the same number of votes, the one with more SMS votes has the advantage
- if they also have the same number of SMS votes, the one which has more SMS votes in the last hour has the advantage
- if they also have the same number of SMS votes in the last hour, they are compared by the hour before, and recursively like that, until there is a difference between the two

Is it possible to do this kind of recursive ordering only in SQL, or do we have to resolve this manually in code? All ideas are welcomed. Just to note, performance is important here, because the top list is used all over the site.

Comment: How do you store SMS votes and time voted for given video, in other table? In other words, add the query which will give the number of SMS votes for given hour for given video.

Comment: Yes. There are 2 more tables, one for sms votes, one for facebook votes

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's feasible to perform this kind of ordering with a recusive calculation (which is potentially unbounded), but if you're willing to limit the amount of time you look back, there are ways it could be done.

Here's one possibility.

```
SELECT video_id,
  SMS_votes + facebook_votes AS total_votes,
  SMS_votes,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR THEN 1 END) AS h1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN time > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR THEN 1 END) AS h2,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN time > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR THEN 1 END) AS h3
FROM videos
JOIN SMS_votes USING(video_id)
GROUP BY video_id
ORDER BY total_votes DESC, SMS_votes DESC, h1 DESC, h2 DESC, h3 DESC;
```

This assumes you have a table called *SMS_votes* tracking each vote, with a *video_id* field and a *time* field.

For each video, it calculates the total votes, the SMS votes, the SMS votes in the past hour, the past two hours, and the past three hours. It then does an `ORDER BY` on all those values to get the correct position.

It's fairly easy to extend this to include a wider range of hours, but you might also want to consider using an increasing time range as you go back in time. For example, you first look at votes in the past hour, then the past day, then the past week, etc. I suspect that would lower your chance of videos having the same votes without having to add as many extra calculations.

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe808/2)

Comment: This is simple but unfortunately not acceptable. We can't limit it to only a few intervals